# Is there a way to list arguments of certain bot commands?

Tags: python, command, discord.py

I am trying to make a an error message for a command, for when you do not include all the arguments, it echos them back to you, for example:

```py
@commands.command()
async def foo(self, ctx, arg1, arg2):
      await ctx.send("You passed: {} and {}".format(arg1, arg2))
```

I know that if I run `>foo` by itself, it will return "arg1 is a required argument that is missing", however I want it to return all of them, for example, something like `Usage: >foo <arg1> <arg2>`

I also know I can always hard-code it using something like this:

```py
@foo.error
async def foo_error(self, ctx, error):
      await ctx.send("``Usage: >foo <arg1> <arg2>``")
```

but I want it so it can automatically do it to any command entered, so I don't have to do it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the error is [`MissingRequiredArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument), and if it is send the help text associated with the command.  You can use [`cog_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.cog_command_error) to run the  error handler for all the errors from the cog:

```
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command()
    async def foo(self, ctx, arg1, arg2):
          await ctx.send("You passed: {} and {}".format(arg1, arg2))
    async def cog_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            message = f"Params are {', '.join(ctx.command.clean_params)}, you are missing {error.param}"
            await ctx.send(message)
        else:
            raise error
```

There are some other attributes of `Command` that you can use instead of `help`, like `brief` or `clean_params`, depending on exactly what you want your output to look like.

Comment: I get a ``HTTPException: 400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message`` when I try that

Answer (score 0):

You could use `*argv` as a parameter, so something like `def foo(self, *args):` and then check if args has the correct length

```
async def foo(self, *args):
    if len(args) != 2:
        await ctx.send("``Usage: >foo <arg1> <arg2>``")
    else:
        # Do something else
```